# Can I use multipart post request to execute synchronous requests?

Tags: javascript, http

I have to execute 3 requests (POST) synchronously.  Is it possible to do it in a single call with multiparts instead of making 3 different calls?

EDIT-

I want them to execute synchronously i.e 2nd request should only execute when first request has been executed and likewise 3rd should only execute when 2nd has been completed.

Reason:
Call to server is very heavy (mainly due to network issue - the servers are in Europe) and I want to do this for better performance.

Thanks

Comment: You really should explain your issue better, with some examples. And why do you want to do that instead of using 3 requests?

Comment: The request is what you decide it to be... if you want to include 3 of them - just do it. As long as the data of 1 doesn't depend on the others - you shouldn't have problems ( and if so it might be even easier to pass the data between the 3 parts I the request handler)

Comment: @SJuan76 - I dont know much about multipart requests (except that for downloading attachments/Email we use it).  I mainly want this for better performance.

Comment: @YaronU. Yes the 2nd could only execute if the first one has been completed and the third one should only execute it first one has been completed. Thanks.

Comment: you can use node.js for that task

Comment: Do you need to get user response based on the first request and pass it to the second?

Comment: multipart requests send different sets of data in one request, for example html, plain text, and xml attachment. are you just submitting the form? you can do this, but it just requires you to keep state between the posts. maybe an iframe is where you post the form and the state is kept on the parent window. then you just have to handle the onload of the iframe.

Comment: As `attila` says, a multipart request is just a request with different chunks of data. But what decides what to do with tha data is the server (in Java world, usually a servlet). Do you control it? You can certainly make a servlet that receives your data and calls 3 inner methods, but you can make a servlet(or equivalent)that does it without using multipart request if you use the right data structure. That said, if the functions required may be different between messages, you will need to define very well the behavior; if they are the same, you just need to define that as a new operation.